# Merging changes in the file located in different directories in git

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm trying to find a better way how to merge changes in a file located in different directories in source and target branches.

- sourceBranch: folder1/folder2/sameFolder/fileWithChanges
- targetBranch: folder3/folder4/sameFolder/fileWithChanges

Maybe it is possible to map directories somehow, to apply changes from folder2 of source branch to folder4 of the target.

Thank you :)

Comment: When you compare the history of the two branches, was the file renamed, or did you and someone else both add the same file to two different folders?

Comment: There is "move" commit in the target branch where the directories structure was changed, but after that development continues in both branches.
"fileWithChanges" modifies in both branches, so such conflicts resolving happens.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "map directories" in Git, but if the file should be in `folder4` after the merge, it means both of you should move the file into `folder4` before merging.

Source branch:

```
git checkout sourceBranch
git mv folder1/folder2/sameFolder/fileWithChanges folder3/folder4/sameFolder/
git commit -m "..."
git checkout targetBranch
git merge sourceBranch
```

Then you can resolve any merge conflicts with `git mergetool`